# Visibility check with JavaScript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, if-statement, visibility

I want to check whether an element with the name "shape_7" is visible. When I perform the following JavaScript it works fine:

```
var element = shape_7;

if( $(element).is(':visible') )
{
//my code
}
```

However, if I perform the following JavaScript it **doesn't** work:

```
var counter = 7;
var element = 'shape_' + counter;

if( $(element).is(':visible') )
{
//my code
}
```

Unfortunately, I need the second case (number as variable) in my situation. How has the second code to be corrected in order to work properly?

Thank you very much in advance for any help!

Comment: Your jQuery calls are looking for `<shape_7>` in the DOM. If you want to find an element with the **id** "shape_7", you want `"#shape_7"`. Otherwise your two pieces of code will do exactly the same thing.

Comment: It appears that `shape_7` is another variable. Where is that coming from? You're defining element as equal to another variable in the first, whereas it's an element selector string in the second. The second is looking for a `<shape_7>` element in your page.

Comment: post your code in https://jsfiddle.net so we can reproduce it.

Comment: I had this problem when using a JavaScript API, so it was quite a special situation. However the answer of Philip works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* access your `shape_*` variables on the `window` object if it is defined globally, so you could do something like `window['shape_' + counter]`.

Again you *can*... But you really shouldn't be coding like that. Instead you should try creating an array with the values:

`var shapes = ['#first', '#second', '#third'];`

Then you can access the values by index: `$(shapes[0]);`

**REMEMBER**

Setting properties on the `window` objects makes them global, which means all code can get and set these property values. It is therefore considering bad practice, and you should try to avoid it. [Look into IIFE's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8228308/5122581)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much for the answer! It works perfectly fine now!

Comment: And thank you for the additional explanation! I will keep it in mind!

Answer (score 0):

```
var counter = 7; 
var element = 'shape_' + counter;
if( $('#'+ element).is(':visible')){//my code}

//or you can use .length if it is visible in the DOM
if( $('#'+ element).length){//my code }
```